# TypeError at / home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Эти коды храняться в разных файлах верхний Blog, нижний в news
Мне надо проверить переменную из Blog в функции news
Что делать?
Заранее спасибо

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from Blog import views

# Create your views here.

def home(request, group):
    if group is None:
        return redirect('/blog')
    else:
        return render(request,'news/index.html')
```

Откуда приходит информация

```
def group_reg(request):
    global group
    group = request.POST['group']
    return redirect('/news')
```

url

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
]
```

Comment: А где вызов функции `home`?

Comment: это в urls.py должно ьыть. нужен этот файл

Comment: в данный момент нельзя дать ответ на ваш вопрос. предоставьте боьлше данных (код в студию, что откуда вызывается, как, и ваши  urls.py)

Comment: Я обновил и вставил url

Comment: Не знаю логику вашего приложения, но хотя бы сделайте второй параметр опциональным: `def home(request, group=None):`, а если планируете руками указать когда нужно передавать `group`, то используйте лямбды: `path('', lambda request: views.home(request, group=True)),`. Если же, у вас значение второго параметра зависит от значения group из `group_reg`, то сделайте group хотя бы глобальной

Comment: "Если же, у вас значение второго параметра зависит от значения group из group_reg, то сделайте group хотя бы глобальной" Мне вот это нужно. Я сделал ее глобальной но все равно эта же ошибка @gil9red

Comment: @Iskramet, убирайте `def home(request, group):` -> `def home(request):`. Убедитесь, что `def home(request` и `def group_reg(request):` находятся в одном файле, тогда хватит простого удаления параметра `group` из `home`

Comment: Мне надо сделать в разных приложениях) Смотрите, у меня есть два приложения(папки)- Blog и news. В html blog Есть форма состоящая из Input и Button . В Input вводим номер группы и нажимая кнопку  начинается работа функции group_reg, которая сохраняет в group номер группы и переходит в приложения news, где включается функция home, где она проверяет переменную group. Ошибка в том что функция home в приложениие news не видет переменную group функции group_reg в     news. Как передать переменную из одного приложения в другое?@gil9red

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости должен быть либо вызов функции home из grope_reg, либо перенаправление с дополнительным аргументом group (если об этой переменной идет речь?). Может быть вам нужна функция [reverse](https://djbook.ru/rel1.4/topics/http/urls.html#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)

Все закомментированные варианты работают:

```
def home(request, i=0):
            return render(request,'home.html',{'i':i})

def redir(request):
            i = request.GET.get('i', None)
            # return redirect('home', i=i )
            # return home(request, i)
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home', kwargs={'i':i}))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home', args=[i]))
```

URLS.PY:

```
from django.urls import path
from APP.view import *

urlpatterns = [
        path('<int:i>/', home, name='home'),
        path('redirect/', redir, name='redir'),
        path('', home, name='home'),

]
```

Comment: Мне надо из одного приложения передать переменную в другое приложение

Comment: Приложения Django - это обычные куски кода python. Что бы запустить что-нибудь ненужное, нужно импортнуть это что-нибудь ненужное. И будет вам доступ до всего, чего душе угодно. Но из того, что я угадываю из ваших "недосказанностей", вам нужна функция reverse

Comment: Мне надо сделать в разных приложениях) Смотрите, у меня есть два приложения(папки)- Blog и news. В html blog Есть форма состоящая из Input и Button . В Input вводим номер группы и нажимая кнопку  начинается работа функции group_reg, которая сохраняет в group номер группы и переходит в приложения news, где включается функция home, где она проверяет переменную group. Ошибка в том что функция home в приложениие news не видет переменную group функции group_reg в     news. Как передать переменную из одного приложения в другое?

Comment: Скорее всего Reverse. Не подскажите как его вставить?) Я просто новичок в django

Comment: Все верно. Вы передаете на сервер номер группы и получаете его в функции представлении  group_reg. Для этого в html должен быть указан урл обработчика формы, а в файле urls должен быть указан ваш обработчик group_reg. Тогда джанга вызовет вашу group_reg. Затем вы должны перенаправить с помощью reverse ваши данные на другой урл. Который также должен быть прописан в одном из файлов urls. Джанга в этот раз вызовет home c вашим параметром урла-адреса. И помните, есть различие между  «параметрами URL-адреса Django» и «параметрами запроса URL».

Comment: Добавил в ответ еще примеры. Если в адресной строке набрать http://вашсайт/redirect/?i=8888888, то получите вызов функции home с аргументом i. Который я в своем примере просто вывел в шаблон.